# Is it possible to "brute-force" material creation through algorithms?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

I know its a bit of a soft question, but lately I've wondered what important properties and calculations would a program that iterates through certain types of molecules and atoms need in order to calculate their individual properties like color, conductivity, reactivity with common substances, etc..

Are there any projects out there that already target something similar to what I have in mind? I know there are a multitude of variables that will come into play, but for the most part say if you were to keep a variety of them constant.

Comment: https://books.google.pl/books?id=kG3SBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA324&lpg=PA324&dq=design+alloy&source=bl&ots=xg8CqY-XrK&sig=tbzhIOMAIAwND93L5zx6gBa0b88&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj13bPH6vXLAhVLG5oKHXKlAgYQ6AEIXzAM#v=onepage&q=design%20alloy&f=false

Comment: This seems related, I would think that there would be more recent books on the subject (this was published in 1977). Surely someone has thought about this before.

Comment: Yeah, I heard about computer design of alloys, maybe I'll find sth. Generally answer seems to be, yes it is possible.

Comment: I found something that seems to be for material design on github (open source software platfor) but it is written in FORTRAN, yikes!.  [MSIM3V](https://github.com/DIDSR/MSim3V_IA)

Comment: Perhaps, I am underestimating the complexity of performing these types of simulations, because it would seem to me that if a close to ideal software of this type was built, there would not be much need for someone to collect actual experimental data.

Comment: MOFS are modelled with computational calculations before they are built.